# Mount a type AUFS using mount() in C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, gnu, mount

I am trying to mount using C program's mount() function instead of terminal command. I could easily implement

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1M none xyz
```

using the following C code:

```
...
asprintf(&options, "size=%s,uid=0,gid=0,mode=777", sz);
rc = mount("tmpfs", mountpoint, "tmpfs", 0, options);
...
```

Now I want to mount a aufs union using the above mount() function. How can I convert the terminal command below to its C implementation, similar to the one I did for tmpfs.

```
mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/lol=rw:/home/shashank/Downloads=ro none /tmp/Combined
```

Comment: maybe try to use system() function? Wrap your settings into string using sprintf() and pass it to system()

Comment: @NickS Thanks for the response. I have kept system() as the last resort as of now since I was wondering if there is any way to use mount directly, which I think is a cleaner way.